# Eclipse 3.5: How to get file name from Editor?

Tags: xml, eclipse, editor

Can anyone tell me how to get file name from editor?

I just made my own editor to open xml file and create
a few section to display the data. Now I want to read
the XML file and place it inside the section.

I think I now how to read xml data but I don't know
how to access the file name so that it can be open.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be [this approach](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg20041.html) could be useful in you casre

> cast the editor input to `IFileEditorInput` and use the `IFile` to call `getLocation()` or `getLocationURI()`.

As said [here](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg35496.html), basically

> `((IFileEditorInput)editorInput).getFile().getLocation()` is enough.

See also [this code](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/pde-dev/msg00444.html):

```
public static String getCurrentFileRealPath(){
        IWorkbenchWindow win = PlatformUI.getWorkbench
().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

        IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();
        if (page != null) {
            IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
            if (editor != null) {
                IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();
                if (input instanceof IFileEditorInput) {
                    return ((IFileEditorInput)input).getFile
().getLocation().toOSString();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code but I got an error on IFileEditorInput.
it say's IFileEditorInput cannot be resolved to a type.
There is suitable solution on quick fix either.

Answer (score 7):

I realise this is old, but since I stumbled upon it while searching for a solution to the exact same problem, I want to add a note to the answer by VonC:

```
IFileEditorInput
```

is hidden in the *org.eclipse.ui.ide* plug-in, so in order for the solution to work your plug-in needs to state that as a dependency.