# Get the Superclass object from the class being edited in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I´m creating my Eclipse plugin here and I´m facing a problem.
I need to recover the Superclass from my Java file being edited at that time, in the Editor.

I could get the path for the file, but it can´t run Class.forName command. It says it can´t find the file.

Does anyone know how to get that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look at the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)

Comment: OK, got the idea.
But I saw that examples list all projects from workspace.

How do I get the current project for the current file? I mean, what if I have many projects? I need to use the current project to continue.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/943030/2670892 for how to get the file currently being edited